# Qt: Change MainWindow Label Text By Click From Dialog

Tags: c++, qt

Case:
App starts, MainWindow opens, then auto-show dialog window (call this A). There's a button in A called 'btn'. In MainWindow, I have a label called 'sometext_label'. What I want is, when 'btn' is clicked, change 'sometext_label' text to "Hi!" for example, and then close dialog A. When dialog A is closed, the label's text should already be changed to "Hi!".

I have written my code and it's trash. It doesn't work. So, how you do it? I've tried using connect function, the signal and slot, but it's not changing anything..

```
//MainWindow.h
...
private slots:
    void Get();
...

//MainWindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    A = new DialogA; //DialogA *A in MainWindow.h
    connect(A, SIGNAL(Send()), this, SLOT(Get()));
}

void MainWindow::Get(){
    ui->Sometext_label->setText("Hi!");
}

//DialogA.h
...
signals:
    void Send();
...

//DialogA.cpp
void DialogA::on_btn_clicked()
{
    emit Send();
}
```

Solution: In my case, I use dialog.exec() function to call the dialog window. Instead, just use dialog.show() function or it won't do good...

Comment: Posted just now.

Comment: It doesn't look that wrong. Though, in the `connect()` you use the ancient Qt4 signals. With Qt5, there is a new concept to get rid of the `SIGNAL()`/`SLOT()` macros with which signal connections are resolved at runtime. Instead, signal connections can be resolved at compile time which makes a wrong connection a compiler error. [Qt doc.: Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: If `DialogA` doesn't become visible, the reason is that you have to add an `A->show();` e.g. in the constructor of `MainWindow`.

Comment: Some samples of mine: [SO: How to make a program with 2 windows that open simultaneously upon runtime in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61677693/7478597), [SO: QT, I made modaless dialog, and now I want to close all dialogs by clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741184/7478597). Please, note: If you have a signal as member of your `ADialog` class you have to use `QOBJECT` in the resp. class definition, and you have to ensure that the MOC stuff is included. For my small samples, I tried to prevent this to make things simpler.

Comment: Yet another sample where I added a signal to a class: [SO: Qt signal slot button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611396/7478597). As I use CMake and VisualStudio, I had to fiddle with the MOC stuff in the CMake script. If you use the tools of Qt, running the MOC stuff is probably even simpler. FYI: [Qt doc.: Using the Meta-Object Compiler (moc)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html)

Comment: Finally solved it after trials and errors... Apparently, if you use Dialog.exec(), the connect function won't do good. Instead, just use Dialog.show(). Is this me being silly or what? -_-

Comment: > 12 hours just for this, thanks.

Comment: Things which are learnt the "hard way" are those which I often can remember best later... ;-)

Comment: QDialog::exec() is nice for modal dialogs especially for message boxes. However, if you want to prevent that a button click closes the dialog then you have to configure that somehow. (I don't remember exactly how. You have RTFM...)

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help.